# Using app hash key as encryption is it good idea?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-security

HI i was thinking to use android app hash key for encrypting data.
I have few questions about this.

1. Is it good idea to hash key it will remain same?
2. Is there any other good way to protect preferences values and string
   api keys in android app source code?
3. Can we extract hash key from released apk? If yes then is it simple
   way?

My above idea is to use hash key as encryption key for encrypting data.
Hopefully i will get some good suggestions about that. Thanks.

Comment: Please post code to obtain hash in your code. Afaik, you can use android keytool to extract key from apk.

Answer (score 0):

Just another suggestion, could you use the [Android Key Store](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore) for this? This would also have the benefit of using a standard well-maintained solution.